# Jquery date picker click with popup not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, datepicker

i am facing problem with on click,basically i have one datepicker and popup,i am willing calling popup on `#contractdate` filed on click but when popup appear with also datepicker calendar,i cant select datepicker date becuase of popup and datepicker appearing on click,how i can resove this?

popup message for contractdate

```
 $('#contractdate').click(function(){
                //$('#notice > p').show();
                $('#intendedNotice').bPopup();

});
```

date picker

```
 $('#contractdate').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function(date,object) {
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply,

```
$('#contractdate').datepicker({ Your init script
  //settings
});

$('#contractdate').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', function(date, object) {
  $('#intendedNotice').bPopup();
});
```

Hope it helps